# Application of pigeonhole principle: proving that two subsets include two or more common integers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

If the proposition below is true, show this.  If false, give a counterexample.
From the integers from $1$ to $11$, make 10 sets $S_1,S_2, \dots, S_{10}$ each with 4 integers selected.  Within each sets, the same number shall not be chosen twice.  No matter how  $S_1,S_2, \dots, S_{10}$ is selected, two sets $S_i,S_j$($i$ not equal to $j$) include two or more common integers.

Is this related to pigeon principle?
$$S_1=\{1,2,3,4\},$$
$$S_2=\{2,3,4,5\},$$
$$S_3=\{4,5,6,7\},$$
$$S_4=\{5,6,7,8\},$$
$$S_5=\{7,8,9,10\},$$
$$S_6=\{8,9,10,11\},$$
$$S_7=\{5,6,2,4\},$$
$$S_8=\{1,5,7,9\},$$
$$S_9=\{4,8,10,11\},$$
$$S_{10}=\{5,7,10,11\}$$

When we choose two of them, there is possibility there are same integer but not all ?
If this is related to pigeonhole principle, Is there possibility that sets are hole and number $1$-$11$ is pigeon but what is the relation with in each sets there are four number?

Comment: Hint:  there are $\binom {11}2=55$ possible pairs of integers taken from $\{1, \cdots, 11\}$.  There are $\binom 42=6$ pairs in each of the $S_i$ hence there are $60$ pairs between all the ten $S_i$.

Comment: Pigeon*hole* principle ?

Comment: @lulu thankyou but after we know all pairs , is there relation with pigeon hole principle?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sorry yes i mean pigeonhole principle

Comment: Think about the numbers.  What do you notice?  Maybe you can spot some pigeons and some holes.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a nit, or more likely being stupid, but I would like to understand this question because it seems interesting, but I don't. If anyone understands it, please can you edit it to make it less ambiguous? What is the actual question?

Comment: @AdamRubinson The way I understand the question:  "From the $11$ integers $\{1, \cdots, 11\}$ we create $10$ sets $S_i$. Each of them contains exactly $4$ of the $11$ integers.  Prove that there are at least two of those sets, $S_i, S_j$ with $i\neq j$ such that $|S_i\cap S_j|≥2$."  In the example given in the post, $S_1,S_2$ fit the bill.

Comment: @lulu i still dont understand, is this related to inclusion exclusion principle? why you chose $\binom {11}2=55$ ? not $\binom {11}4$? and also when we choose two of sets, not all have common integer, so i should disprove the statement?

Comment: The question concerns pairs of integers, so it is natural to count the possible pairs.  As an easier warm up exercise, prove that the $S_i$ can't all be disjoint.  The logic is the same, the warm up works with single elements and the actual problem works with pairs of elements.

Comment: @AdamRubinson  I should add:  the problem does not specify whether or not the proposed result is true.  Thus, you are asked to prove it, if it is true, and to find a counterexample to it if it is false.

Comment: Thanks for your replies lulu. I'll have to think about it tomorrow as it's getting late here.

Comment: @lulu Thankyou but i still dont understand why you chose $\binom {11}2=55$ and $\binom 42=6$ and what is the relation with 10 sets? is this also related to pigeonhole principle/inclusion exclusion?

Comment: Please try.  Did you do the warmup exercise I suggested?

Comment: Honestly, my initial hint is $95\%$ of a complete solution...I don't see what else I can say other than writing out the answer.  Well, do the warm up exercise I proposed.  It's considerably easier than the given problem, and the logic behind that is identical.

Comment: @lulu I still dont understand what is the relation between pair of integer, and also choose 4 number from 11 to make sets? and from my example , if i choose two sets such as S5 and S1, is it enough to disprove the proposition  that if i choose any two sets ,  $|S_i\cap S_j|≥2$ does not always hold?

Comment: Please look at my comments.  I never spoke of $\binom {11}4$, I don't see how that value comes up. And, no, of course it is not enough to exhibit two sets that do not have a pair (or more) in common.  Why would that be enough?  Have you done the warm up exercise?

Comment: I really like the hint from @lulu but here's a different (and perhaps easier?) hint: First prove that an integer can appear in at most $3$ sets.

Comment: @antkam is it because $\lceil \frac{11}{4} \rceil$ so at least 3 integer in each sets? i still dont understand the hint and is this related to inclusion principle or pigeonhole principle

Comment: @lulu It is quite late, but i got the idea of your hint, i just want to make sure again, $\binom {11}2=55$ i know there are 55 different pairs of numbers , while there are 60 of total pairs in 10 sets, but why you have to count in pairs not 4 ? because $|S_i\cap S_j|≥2$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT (different from lulu's)

> Lemma: some integer must appear in $4$ or more sets.

Proof of Lemma: apply pigeonhole based on there being $11$ integers, $10$ sets, each of size $4$. $\square$

> Main Claim: some pair $S_i, S_j$ must share $2$ or more integers.

Proof:  By Lemma, there is an integer, call it $s$, which appears in (at least) $4$ sets, e.g.:

$$\{s,a,b,c\}, \{s,d,e,f\},\{s,g,h,i\}, \{s,j,k,l\}$$

Use pigeonhole principle again to show two of these sets must share $2$ or more integers.  $\square$

Hope you can finish based on the above?

Comment: Thankyou, for the proof some integer must appear in 4 more sets, there are 11 integer, but each sets size 4, so by pigeon hole principle, we need at least 3 sets in order two sets out of three have at least 1 same number on it. since there are 10 sets, $\lceil \frac{10}{3} \rceil =4$ ?  but I'm not sure what is the pigeon and pigeonhole in this? and i think there are some integer that only appear in 3 sets too, if i put 1..11 to each sets from S1 to 10 then 8,9,10,11 only appear 3 times in S1..S10 sets(?)

Comment: For the Lemma, count the appearances.  There are $10$ sets, each of size $4$, so the integers must collectively appear $40$ times.  There are $11$ integers.  If each one appeared $3$ times or fewer, that cannot fill the $40$ appearances.

Comment: Thankyou for the hint. But i think it should be that some integer must appear in 3 or 4 more sets ? if all integer appear in 4 sets , it must be 44 appearance and need 11 sets?  and for the pair, if one integer appear in 4 sets, there are 3 spot left in every sets, and 10 distinct integer left , by pigeon hole principle, we can put 3 different integer in 3 sets, but in fourth sets there must be integer that we already put in the S1,S2, or S3 , so either  $S1 \cap S4 $ or $S2 \cap S4 $ or $S3 \cap S4 $ , it this enough to proof?

Comment: for the lemma, you don't care about integers which appear in $3$ sets.  all you need is that _some_ integer appears in at least $4$ sets.  and for the second part, yes you are right.

Comment: Thankyou but why it has to be 4? and i dont understand the relation between 11 integer, 10 sets and each size 4, for example there are only 6 sets each 4 integer and 11 integer to put, with only 6 sets, we also can get two sets that share two or more integer?

Comment: Do you understand what the question is asking?  The statement is _no mattter_ how the $10$ sets are chosen, two of them must share two (or more) common integers.  So the fact that you can exhibit an example (with only $6$ sets) is irrelevant.  They are asking you to prove no counter-example can exist, and you're showing that examples exist.

Comment: Yes thankyou for the explanation, but i want to know the reason why they pick 10 sets , 11 integer and in each sets there are 4 integer? Usually in pigeonhole principle problem, we need to find the bound so we can apply the theorem or if the data is smaller than the bound we cannot apply the theorem(?)